# Calling a shell function (in an external file) with arguments from a makefile

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I have a file sedstr.sh containing a function sedstr:

```
#!/bin/bash
function sedstr {
# From stackoverflow.com/a/29626460/633251 (Thanks Ed!)
    old="$1"
    new="$2"
    file="${3:--}"
    escOld=$(sed 's/[^^]/[&]/g; s/\^/\\^/g' <<< "$old")
    escNew=$(sed 's/[&/\]/\\&/g' <<< "$new")
    sed -i.tmp "s/\<$escOld\>/$escNew/g" "$file" # added -i.tmp
    echo "sedstr done"
}
```

I have an external file "test" to be edited in place with these contents:

```
My last name is Han.son and I need help.
If the makefile works, I'll have a new last name.
```

I want to call the sedstr function with its arguments from a makefile.  Nothing should be returned, but the external file should be edited.  Here is a small makefile that doesn't work:

```
all: doEdit

doEdit:
  $(shell ./sedstr.sh) # I was hoping this would bring the function into the scope, but nay
  $(shell sedstr 'Han.son', 'Dufus', test)
```

How can I call this function using variables in the makefile?  The error is:

```
make: sedstr: Command not found
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

Comment: Why have the commands in a function?

Comment: @EtanReisner Thank you.  The extra `$(shell ... )` was left over from when the line was not in a target.  So I removed that and the extra commas (silly), now I have `./sedstr.sh; sedstr 'Hans.son' 'Dufus' test` and it gives the following error: `MWE2:7: *** missing separator.  Stop.` With the `$(shell ... )` I get the error I originally reported.

Comment: @MikkelChristiansen Having the function externally was suggested in a another question as a more sensible approach.

Comment: What was the missing separator?

Comment: I had used spaces instead of tab (obviously new to this).

Comment: sed might not use \< and \>. It isn't standard regex.

Comment: Hmm... I got the function [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29626460/633251) but I just tested it with the example at that page, and it doesn't seem to work in my context.  I need to regroup and make sure I'm doing everything correctly.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You noticed that you have `Han.son` in the file but `'Hans.son'` in the makefile snippet? Also your edit to `sedstr` to make it a function complicates the usage in a makefile where using it as a script would be simpler (no sourcing required first).

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes, another sharp-eyed person caught that typo but that isn't the problem (I'll edit the question).  Thank you.  Right now I think I have the call to the function working correctly but it may be that the function itself is not working - I need to investigate further.

Comment: The function works. I tested both the original and your version on your test file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each line in a make recipe is executed in its own shell.

Similarly, so is each call to `$(shell)`.

They don't share state.

To do what you want ould would need a recipe line of

```
$(shell . ./sedstr.sh; sedstr 'Han.son' 'Dufus' test)
```

That being said there's **no** reason to use `$(shell)` here at all as you are already in a shell context and as you can just as easily (and more correctly) use a recipe line of

```
. ./sedstr.sh; sedstr 'Hans.son' 'Dufus' test
```

And yes, the commas in the original are just incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on the 'big picture'.  If I use the direct approach, it complains `/bin/sh: sedstr: command not found` which is not the shell I thought I was using...

Comment: make uses `/bin/sh` by default but that's not really relevant here. The second attempt here had a typo, you need to source the script and not run it as a script on its own.

Comment: Got it, error eliminated, but it doesn't carry out the editing.  I'm doubting the function now, see my comments above under the original question.  Thanks for you help.

Comment: I got it working now.  No problem with the sedstr function.  Seemed to be a problem with crossing my test functions and test files, and also, unsaved edits were not being seen in testing.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Final question: In `. ./sedstr.sh; ...` what does the first `.` do?

Comment: `source`/`.` loads a script file in the current session.

Comment: But doesn't `./sedstr.sh` do that?  I'm still confused about the leading `.`  Unfortunately this stuff is sort of hard to look up!

Comment: No, `./sedstr.sh` runs the script as a script. So the function only exists in the shell context of the script that ends immediately when the file ends. `.` loads the script in the *current* shell context. Look for `source` in the bash man page.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the function from inside sedstr.sh. At the end

```
sedstr "$1" "$2" "$3"
```

EDIT
Or see other answer

Comment: I assume I put that after the function definition.  What do I put in the makefile?

Comment: ./sedstr.sh 'Hans.son' 'Dufus' test

Comment: OK, I did it as you said, and I get this result: `./sedstr.sh 'Hans.son' 'Dufus' test; sedstr done` which seems reasonable.  A test.tmp file is created as expected, but the file contents are not edited. So... maybe the function isn't working?

Comment: I notised Han.son in test and Hans.son as argument?

Comment: Ugh... too tired.  Thanks.  But fixing that didn't lead to an edited file.  I'm checking to make sure I've got it all correct.

Comment: I got it working now.  No problem with the sedstr function.  Seemed to be a problem with crossing my test functions and test files, and also, unsaved edits were not being seen in testing.  Thanks for your help.